# General facebook posting program for multiple people

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is kind of broad but I'm having an incredibly difficult time finding what I should do here.

I've created a facebook posting platform on our site, which has several hundred users. Some of these users have facebook accounts and we want to have the ability to create posted campaigns for them by using this interface to create a post caption, tags and a photo, getting their user API key from the database and then posting on their behalf.

However, I'm not really sure how to do this. The users can add us as admins on their page, but I'm hoping to be able to direct them to get a key/token that we can have them enter to our DB and use that on a call in the interface once the content is created.

Basically if we want to post for user 123, I would grab their API key from the database once the form is submitted and then take the post/tag(s) and photo URL from the page and post to their page.

How feasible is this and what exactly should I use to achieve this?

Comment: Send them through the login flow, ask them for the necessary permissions, use the resulting token afterwards …

Comment: Is there documentation for this particular process that I'm doing though? Can this be done without them creating an app for their facebook?

Comment: @04fs so is this possible with multiple people? Say I created a post and wanted to immediately post it on 5 differen't users pages as a blast?

Comment: @04FS this is under the umbrella of us having been already added as an admin on their page

Comment: You just need the page tokens for the respective pages, which you get from `/me/accounts`

Comment: So let's say our personal facebook page is the one posting on behalf of them and our page is an admin on their side, I would just need to make the call for each user with our info? And we would only need our page to be an app, but not theirs?

Comment: @Whisou138 pages are not apps, and neither is your page an admin of anything. If anything, _user_ accounts are admins of a page.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: We have a user account for our company that also has a page, which we've registered with an App id through the developer site.Our user account is the admin for 20-30 of our users' pages

Comment: Then your user just needs to grant the permissions `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` to the app. A request to `/me/accounts` gets you the pages and their respective access tokens, that you need to post on that particular page.

Comment: Oh I think I see now. So with our user having admin access to about 26 pages, then me/accounts will return all 26 pages and their respective tokens